# Sparse quadratic programming solver

Tags: software, quadratic-programming

For a hobby project I need to solve a series of quadratic programming problems each with

- about 500 variables
- about 1000 constraints, each of the form $x_i-x_j\le c_{ij}$
- the objective function is the sum of about 300 terms of the form $w_{ij}^2(x_i-x_j+d_{ij})^2$
- about a third of the variables are ignored by the objective function, and are just there to help organize the constraints.

I imagine there must be off-the-shelf solvers that can do this, but I'm quite new to this area, and the list of solvers at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) is not really helpful in terms of selecting which one to look into. Could someone help point me towards a good choice, please?

I'm looking for something that is free and with not too much of a learning curve just to put a problem into it and get a solution. Needing to write some glue code in C/C++, Java, Perl or the like is not a showstopper, however.

Comment: Do you have any other requirements/restrictions? The gold standard QP solvers are CPLEX and Gurobi, which are commercial, but have free academic licenses. For open source solvers, IPOPT is a good general purpose nonlinear programming solver; I'd have to look around at open source QP solvers to refresh my memory. (Edit: CVXOPT is also a fine choice of open source solver, if you know Python.)

Comment: @Geoff: Which kind of requirements/restrictions are you envisaging? Unfortunately, since I'm not in academia those commercial solvers are not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cvxopt (for python) does QP, and can take advantage of sparsity (you can provide a custom KKT solver specific to your problem). An example of a custom solver is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cvxopt/W8kd3LHPwwA

Comment: I suppose I could learn enough Python to write a wrapper that reads the problem from stdin ... but are you saying I'd have to "provide a custom KKT solver" in order to get it to handle my problem size? I don't even know what that is.

Comment: Re. KKT, I found [this at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Necessary_conditions). Once I evaluate the gradients, those conditions seem to reduce to exactly the problem I had _before_ I reformulated it as a QP problem in the hope of getting some off-the-shelf software to solve it for me. If I have to provide a custom solver for the KKT formulation of my problem, it would look like Cvxopt wouldn't actually provide any value over just using that custom solver directly?

Comment: See the cvxopt documentation ( http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html ) for a description of the problem. From your description, the QP problem will require solving a linear equation with a 1500x1500 matrix, so storage shouldn't be a problem. If you don't take advantage of sparsity, solving a dense matrix system takes O(N^3) time, which should take a few tenths of a second on a normal PC. You could reduce that to O(number of nonzero entries) with a custom solver, which may not be worth the extra complexity.

Comment: I'm using it now, works like a charm. Thank you!